# changing image source using jquery

Tags: jquery

I've datatable in my project. I'm loading it dynamically. I want to put on it a image preview section and I want to extract the file path from the database. I use this code to build dynamically datatable.

```
<script>
if($.fn.dataTable.isDataTable( '#example' )){
    var table = $('#example').DataTable();
}
function getData(){
    $('#example tbody').html('');
    var URL_PREFIX="http://localhost:8983/solr/archiveCore/select?q=strSO_copy:";
    var URL_MIDDLE="AND PackName_copy:";
    var URL_SUFFIX="AND DocType_copy:";
    var strSO="\"" + $("#ngramBoxstrSO").val() + "\"";
    var PackName="\"" + $("#ngramBoxPackName").val() + "\"";
    var DocType="\"" + $("#ngramBoxDocType").val() +"\"";
    var URL=URL_PREFIX + strSO + URL_MIDDLE + PackName + URL_SUFFIX + DocType;
    $.ajax({
        url:URL,
        dataType:'jsonp',
        jsonp : 'json.wrf',
        type :'get',
        cache :false,
        success: function(data){
            var docs=data.response.docs;
            var html='';
            $.each(docs,function(key,value){
                html+='<tr>';
                html+='<td>'+value.id+'</td>';
                html+='<td>'+value.strSO+'</td>';
                html+='<td>'+value.PackName+'</td>';
                html+='<td>'+value.DocType+'</td>';
                html+='<td>'+value.DocName+'</td>';
                html+='<td class="text-center"><button id="'+value.FilePath+'" type="button" onclick="openDocument(this.id)" class="btn btn-sm" >OPEN</td>';
                html+='<td class="text-center"><a href="#" class="preview">Image Preview<img id="images" src="" class="hide-image"></a></td>';
                html+='</tr>';
                if(value.extType=="JPG")
                    {
                        $("#images").attr("src",value.FilePath);
                        console.log(value.FilePath);
                    }
            });
            $('#example').DataTable().destroy();
            $('#example tbody').html(html);
            var table=$('#example').DataTable({
                "aaSorting" : [],

            });
        },
    });


};
</script>
```

When I run my project, the image source is not changing. Where is the problem? I couldn't find it.

Comment: Firstly, note that you're duplicating the same `id` multiple times in the HTML you add to the DOM. You need to use unique ids, or a common class. Also, have you debugged this to check if the AJAX request is successful? Are there any errors in the console? What's the value of `data` when the response completes? If the path in `key.FilePath` valid for the domain you're calling it from?

Comment: I made some changes my codes. I get the file path using `value.FilePath` but the image source problem still in progress.

Comment: check the answer it might help you bro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using jquery you can access of the attr "src" in img tag and change as such you want check the below code it might help you.

```js
$('img[name="image"]').attr('src','updatedBathri');  // where image is the name of the image tag
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="bathri" name="image"/>
```

Comment: @MustafaBerkanDemir check two things ,1. is there is value in value.FilePath  2. #images id should be only for that particular image tag because id will work only the first element if it is given for many tags. Give unique id for the particular image tag or access it by name.

Comment: the first option is ok, I give unique id the image tag at second option but the image not coming. I checking if the file path isn't correct, but it's true. I tried another image file, it's not coming to.

Comment: right click on the image tag and select inspect option.then check the src tag ,is it is having the path which u want. if it is there then there is not problem in the code you need to updated the url of the image.

Comment: When I select inspect option it seems like this `src(unknown)` . So I think the problem is here `$("#showImage").attr("src",value.FilePath);`

Comment: @MustafaBerkanDemir $("#images").attr("src",value.FilePath) this is the id which you have given for the image tag use this. undefined means there is no value in value.FilePath. do get value in console.log for that which you have already used

Comment: Ok, I made it like this `html+='<td class="text-center"><a href="#" class="preview">Image Preview<img id="showImage" src="'+value.FilePath+'" class="hide-image"></a></td>';`. But there is another problem :) When the file type isn't jpg, I want to disable mouse over event. I tried something to fix it but I don't make it yet.

Comment: Use this css to diable mouve over event. .element {
    pointer-events: none;
} vote the question if u have got a answer, so it will be use ful for others